# Solution Verification: $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ and $B\in M_{n\times m}(F)$ for which $m>n$, show $AB$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

$M_{m\times n}(F)$ is the set of all $m\times n$ matrices over field $F$. Now if we multiply $k$ elementary matrices from the left side by $A$, we will reach an RREF (row-reduced echelon form) matrix row-equivalent to $A$ that we call it $R$: $\underbrace{P_kP_{k-1}\dots P_1}_{P}A=PA=R$. Because $A$ has more rows that columns, it will at most have $n$ pivots. So it will have at least $m-n$ zero rows. Now if we calculate $PAB$, we'll have:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
&&&&\dots\\
&&&&\vdots\\
0&&0&&\dots&&0
\end{bmatrix}_{m\times n}\times B_{n\times m}=
\begin{bmatrix}
&&&&\dots\\
&&&&\vdots\\
0&&0&&\dots&&0
\end{bmatrix}_{m\times m}$$
As it has a zero row, it can't be row-equivalent to identity matrix. It shows $PAB$ is not an invertible matrix. But we know elementary matrices are invertible, so their products are. Hence, $P$ is invertible. It shows $AB$ is not invertible, because if it was we would face a contradiction that $(AB)^{-1}(P)^{-1}$ is the inverse of $PAB$ that we previously proved is not invertible.

Comment: This is more easily argued in terms of rank.  What is the rank of an invertible matrix?  What can you say about the rank of a product of two matrices?

Comment: You can have an easier way: see $A$ and $B$ as linear maps $A : F^n \to F^m$ and $B: F^m \to F^n$. You can check that $g \circ f$ injective $\implies \ f$ injective (or dually $g \circ f$ surjective $\implies \ g$ surjective), so here $AB = A \circ B$ is neither injective nor bijective since neither $B$ is injective, nor $A$ is surjective.

Comment: @MarkSDavis My linear algebra course hasn't reached to rank definition and I can't use it to solve the problem. Is my approach correct?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I'm not allowed to use linear maps. Just, is my approach correct?

Comment: wow, how was linear algebra introduced to you then? Is it the "weird" American technique where you first see matrix computations and then linear maps? Your approach is correct though

Comment: The proof is fine, very clearly argued, in fact.  When you do get to linear maps, rank, and the rank-nullity theorem, make sure you revisit this problem to see how those ideas simplify the proof.